# AWS IoT MQTT on ESP8266 -- Put Secret Key on Device?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, internet-of-things

I am setting up an IoT device using this library (https://github.com/odelot/aws-mqtt-websockets) to connect to the AWS IoT service. I have it working and it works well, however, I have a bit of a question about the device's use of an AWS user's secret key.

In order to set up the library, you create an IAM user with only IoT permissions, then generate a key and secret and load that onto the IoT device. The IoT device then uses that information to connect through the library to the AWS IoT MQTT service.

I was always taught to **NEVER** put a secret key onto a client facing device. So, I am wondering

1. Is this secure / how so?
2. Do I need to create a new IAM user for every account?
3. Is this common practice?
4. Would a service such as Cognito be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you don't put IAM User *Access key* and *Secret key* onto the end user device. Never. And you don't create IAM User for each IoT node either.

Instead each AWS IoT device will get its own **IoT credential file** (created as part of the device registration). Not the *IAM keys* but these *IoT keys* are what you upload to the device.

I believe there are 3 PEM files per device - *certificate*, *private key* and *public key*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I looked around and found the correct solution burried in the weeds. Glad to know my instinct of NEVER putting in a private key is still good. In case anyone is looking for how to use certificates with an ESP8266, this github project has proven useful: https://github.com/copercini/esp8266-aws_iot